Chebyshev's inequality for sample mean (weak law of large numbers)
hello guys in my book there is an inequality which i do not understand (line 2 in the image). they want to prove the weak law of large numbers
it says that i can take any k that is greater then...
but this is absurd, example:
if i choose:
epsilon=1, standard deviation=2, and sample size 5, choosing any k could absurdly guarantee a near-certain probability of the distance being at most 1 from the sample mean.

Please provide detailed context: what assumptions are made, what the symbols are. Currently, it is bit haphazard.

Welcome to CV, Roei. For a better understanding of this result and its use, please search our site for Chebyshev Inequality.  The duplicates have good answers elaborating on the points you bring up.
